# Element xsl:mode must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet

Tags: java, saxon

Am getting this error, when using `<axsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in my xslt 3.0. lib --> `saxon-ee:9.7.0.4`

```
Error at /xsl:stylesheet/xsl:mode[1] 
  XTSE0010: Element xsl:mode must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet
Error at /xsl:stylesheet/xsl:mode[1] 
  XTSE0010: Element xsl:mode must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet
Error at /xsl:stylesheet/xsl:mode[1] 
  XTSE0010: Unknown XSLT element: mode
```

When I use the latest `SaxonEE9-8-0-14`, am not sure how to use the `Serializer. net.sf.saxon.s9api.Serializer`

```
// destination
            Serializer serializer = new Serializer(); // This worked with 9.7 but errors with 9.8
            serializer.setOutputWriter(writer);
            serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
            serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.setDestination(serializer);
```

Help Please

Comment: In Saxon 9.8 there is http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor.html#newSerializer-- so you can create a `Serializer serializer = processor.newSerializer();`. Does that help? As for the XSLT error with Saxon 9.7, are you sure you have a `version="3.0"` on the generated stylesheet?

Comment: I've taken on board that the diagnostics here could be better. There's some redundant validation going on, and I've fixed this for the next release.

Comment: @Martin The suggestions mentioned worked. regarding saxon 9.7 it does not work in-spite of version 3.0

Answer (score 0):

The latest release is Saxon 9.8. The previous 9.7 came out before the XSLT 3.0 recommendation was finalised, so XSLT 3.0 features were available only if explicitly requested (for example by setting version="3.0" on the stylesheet).

The free-standing constructor for a `Serializer` was deprecated in 9.6 and 9.7 in favour of using the factory method `Processor.newSerializer()`, and the public constructor was finally dropped in 9.8. This is because unless the `Serializer` has access to the `Configuration` that underpins the `Processor`, it can't do anything that needs to take account of configuration settings.